# Does hCard understand encodings?

Tags: utf-8, hcard

I'm using the Operator extension to firefox.

When I go to http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard (which is encoded as utf-8) and try to export the hCard for Tantek Çelik (at the top) to Outlook, it comes through as Tantek Ã‡elik.

Does anyone know if this is a problem with Outlook, the Operator extension, or if the hCard microformat just doesn't support encodings?

I've tried using the &...; equivalent, with the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hCard is a means of transcoding vCard to HTML.  vCard itself does not specify character encodings for its content, but a MIME `Content-Type` header used to deliver the vCard data, such as over HTTP, can specify an encoding.  The vCard data has to be decoded to Unicode, then converted to HTML in whatever encoding the HTML uses.  I am not familiar with Operator, but I suspect either it is not decoding/encoding the hCard correctly before importing to Outlook, or the MicroFormats website is not formatting the hCard correctly to begin with.

Comment: I do believe vCard (not to be confused with the hCard microdata format or the vcard class of the hCard microdata format) can specify encoding for content, e.g. `FN;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:Foo`. Microformats are embedded into the html document, and as such do not have a separate MIME type.

Comment: `ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE` is a binary data encoding, not a character encoding (BTW, `QUOTED-PRINTABLE` is no longer supported by the vCard spec after 2.1). There is a big difference. The vCard spec that hCard is based on (RFC 2426) does not support inline charset encodings, and explicitally says that the charset used for non-ASCII text must be specified outside of the vCard, such as by a MIME header, HTML charset, etc. vCard 4 (RFC 6350) eliminates that possibility, requiring UTF-8 for non-ASCII text and explicitally forbids external sources from overriding that requirement.

Comment: Thank you for the references.